# Stop displaying the CAPTCHA if you take too long to edit

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, captcha

I can understand being forced to pass the CAPTCHA test if you post too quickly, but I can see no reason for it if you post too slowly?  So what if I take 15 minutes composing my question or answer?  How could that possibly be used for abuse?  Would you prefer my post was full of typos and incorrect information?

Don't rush me!

---

**Note**: This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2085/why-show-captcha-when-an-answer-takes-too-long).  That question is asking why it is happening.  I don't care why it is happening, I want it to stop because I can't see any reason for it.  I am requesting a bug fix.

---

2009-08-15:  Why was this marked completed?  It wasn't.  I am still annoyed by that CAPTCHA when I take too long to compose a question.  Why?  Please explain the logic behind that decision.

Comment: Related to this (though not an exact duplicate) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2236/stop-popping-the-captcha-if-you-take-too-long-to-edit

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2085/why-show-captcha-when-an-answer-takes-too-long/2097#2097

Comment: Captcha is so annoying here i can't stand it i have to type it over and over like i came to stackoverflow to play a captcha game

Answer (score 3):

I have never seen the CAPTCHA displayed for posts taking a long time to write (perhaps I write too fast). If this is the case, I can't think of any legit reason why it would be doing that.

Answer (score -6):

Some reductions in CAPTCHA throttle thresholds, **if you have > 10k rep**:

- for edits -- reduced by two-thirds
- for post submission times -- min seconds reduced by one half, max minutes increased by 2x

Comment: Is this supposed to answer my question?  It doesn't.  I will try to make it simpler.  Why am I "challenged" (i.e., I am treated like I am doing something wrong) if I take too long to compose a question or answer?

Comment: your account could be compromised, just like anyone else's. even moderators are subject to these limits. You seem angry. I'm not sure what else to tell you.

Comment: That is one of the flaws of written communication.  Much can be lost and much can incorrectly inferred.  Unless, perhaps, you're a brilliant writer, which I am not.  I'm not angry, I just haven't received a complete explanation of the logic behind this design decision.  How can my account be compromised if I take too long to compose a question or answer?  How does simply having to type two words into a text box protect my account, should it become compromised?

Comment: i got irritated enough to search on meta to add support for drastic reductions in captcha thresholds

Comment: >10K? That's a tiny number of users.  It should be more like >1K.

Comment: @finnw: Gaining >1K for spamming purposes could be done within 4-5 days if wanted.

Comment: @Andrew: you can't spam if you have 10k rep. The limits are still there, they are still more relaxed.

Comment: @Koper: Manual spamming is still possible... Anyway, the whole idea of having a rep-limit here is to associate with user-trust. At 1K, the cost of building that trust is minimal. At 10K, its more costly.