# Eliminate the captcha on long questions & answers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, captcha

It seems that I quite often get a captcha confirmation when I post a question or answer.  All it takes is to write a longish piece of text or check a couple of things to make sure what I am saying is on track.  I can easily spend 15 to 20 minutes on an answer if I am being careful and thorough, especially if I paste in links to back up what I am saying.

This always makes me nervous, as well as being a pain/annoyance. What if the recaptcha site doesn't work properly? What if I lose my internet connection while doing it (happens a lot on my laptop due to a faulty wireless card)? What if I get the captcha wrong?  It becomes easy to lose 15 - 30 minutes of work just because SO imposed an additional step on me.

Is this "too long" check really necessary?  I mean, how long *should* it take a human to type 1000 characters of text?  You can't really say, since it depends on the content.  Certainly you can set a threshold of where it's too fast, but not where it's too slow.

Comment: I already complained about this to no avail: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2236/stop-displaying-the-captcha-if-you-take-too-long-to-edit  I still don't understand how, but Jeff feels something bad could happen if you take too long to edit a post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

due to popular demand, I removed the maximum time check as a CAPTCHA trigger.

Now you can take hours, *days*, nay ... *WEEKS* ... to compose the very best answer possible!

Comment: Slowest gun in the west problem?

Answer (score 3):

Copy/paste your answer into notepad before hitting submit. It's become a habit of mine on sites that I don't trust (I've not had troubles on the SOFU sites yet, thank goodness)

Comment: Yeah, I wish this weren't true.  HTML 5 has some offline features that could take care of that, but I doubt they'll be implemented here for this type of problem.  I also wish that the length of time allowed to post an answer before showing the captcha got longer the more rep you have...

Comment: Answers the what if it fails, but not the extra step annoyance, and requires that I perform yet another extra step.

Comment: @Pollyanna, it does.  It kicks in at 10K.  A cop-out IMHO (because if Jeff got that number wrong (which he obviously did) the extra spam is easy to clean up by hand.)  I wonder how many people who are careless enough to have their accounts compromised are still able to get 1K rep.  Probably not many.  I assume Jeff is choosing to err on the side of avoiding the extra work.

Answer (score 3):

> What if the recaptcha site doesn't work properly? What if I loose my internet connection while doing it

...what if there's no captcha, but things fail anyhow? I always get my post, no matter how small, onto my clipboard before hitting submit on *any* site...

Comment: I'm not sure how a failed Internet connection could be considered a bug in the site, either.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do you take advantage of the preview window so as to not submit until you are satisfied with your edit?  I usually only have two or three edits register when I am posting, even for extensively thought-out posts involving a lot of code and details; I also use the Firefox plugin "[It's All Text!](https://addons.mozilla.org/el/firefox/addon/4125)" so I can use my editor of choice (vim) for writing my post, which really helps out when writing code on the fly.

Comment: This happens on initial post, without any editing, just because you take too long in constructing the post.