# What is the fkey that's present on some pages and what does it do?

Tags: discussion

I am a bit reluctant to ask this question since it may appear sinister (or that it may belong to SO), but my curiosity has peaked: I'm wondering what the "fkey" does that gets sent with a new comment.

I [read here that using a token can help prevent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32910/how-does-stackoverflow-reduce-prevent-spam-while-allowing-unregistered-users-to-p/32996#32996) some forms of session hijacking. I would like to understand how that process works. Is the "fkey" an example of this? I don't need or want a detailed description of what SO does with the "fkey"; I would like an overview of the technical aspects of such security a technique (if my assumptions are correct) and any further reading.

Perhaps this question is better suited for SO, but it seems as relevant to SO as it is to the backdrop of the topic.

Comment: Thanks for your question. I would actually like to know Stackexchange's implementation of this fkey. It's used everywhere in their js and sent in post requests.

Comment: @David, I would to. I haven't had a chance to do any further research, but I plan to tackling this issue at some point when I have time. If you make any further progress, please share by writing a comment here with @Mohamad in the first line, or posting a whole new answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It provides [XSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) protection. Something that can't be known to an attacker (it is different per user). Cookies are #fail because the browser will add them implicitly.

From the [section on "prevention"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Prevention):

> Requiring a secret, user-specific token in all form submissions and side-effect URLs prevents CSRF; the attacker's site cannot put the right token in its submissions