# StackExchange Bugs in IE10 on Windows 8

Tags: support, windows-8, internet-explorer-10

Multiple bugs on SE sites for IE10 on Windows 8:

- Unable to upvote or downvote
  [image]
- Unable to edit a question
  [image]
- Asking a question without a title generates a validation error: title required.  After entering a title, validation error remains.

Is there a timeline to fix these?  The first two bugs are killer.

---

This is the response body I got while trying to edit a post:

```
javascript';
        sc.async=true;
        sc.src='http://edge.quantserve.com/quant.js'; 
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(sc,s);
    })();
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        _qevents.push({ qacct: "p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc" });
    </script>    

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like JavaScript is blocked for some reason. Can you check JS console?

Comment: Anyway, IE10 [is still not supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) - so this isn't a bug just yet.

Comment: IE10 is the current release of IE on the current platform.  Win8 has reached RTM.  The wikipedia page referenced on that question only lists the release previews of Win8.

Comment: I won't argue on that, but until that linked post will be updated it means Stack Exchange sites are not officially supporting IE10 that's all.

Comment: I don't see any errors in the JS console.  JavaScript is enabled and seems to be working fine.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, update the linked page then. It doesn't appear (based on the edit history) that Stackexchange employees update it as, and I quote, it is "the community's best guess".... Note that the answer from Jeff states that "We support current and previous versions" and "formally released browsers are supported". On that basis I'd suggest Internet Explorer 10 is supported. There is **nothing official** about a list which is given with the caveat "the community's best guess" =) (All that said, SO was working for me last night on IE10!)

Comment: I have made the proper updates.  These can now be considered bugs.

Comment: OK fair enough Nathan and @Rob. Still, can you check the JavaScript console to see if it contains any clues?

Comment: @NathanDeWitt - IE10 is *not* the current release, it's released **to manufacturing**, that's not the same as "released"...that's "released with restrictions".  There are more bug fixes to IE coming before general availability.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, I mentioned earlier.  No errors in the script console.

Comment: @Nick I did a research and everything I found said that RTM is the same as final release. :/

Comment: I can't reproduce any of this behavior with IE10 on Windows 8 RTM.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn - I don't know what to tell you.  I included screenshots.  This is Win8 RTM as well.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Like he said, RTM is only available for OEMs and specific groups of consumers, but not to the general public. There is no technical difference, but there is a marketing difference, so to speak. But we all know that Windows 8 is landing in just 3 days anyway, so...

Comment: RTM is released to developers and sysadmins so that these types of bugs can be found and fixed prior to the general public getting the errors.  As a developer, I can be told "check the JS console" but Joe Blow will just view the site as broken and never use it again.

Comment: OK. Do those errors happen all the time? If you try to edit different post, do you succeed?

Comment: Errors happen all the time.  First noticed the errors and [asked about it 7 months ago](http://superuser.com/questions/404129/javascript-errors-in-ie10).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - that's just not true these days, for example there's already been multiple updates to Windows 8 (one major) between RTM and when it's actually available for everyone.

Comment: @Nick OK fair enough. However, I do agree with Nathan that such bugs should be handled just like any other bugs.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - if we're sure the software is shipping soon and has bugs of course we take a look, but all of the claims here are non-repro by everyone...so not sure what we can do to fix a bug very localized to this user.  My guess would be a bad proxy is in play here.

Comment: @Nick bad proxy blocking some .js file(s) makes sense.. Nathan can you view the network traffic in the browser and see if some content is being blocked?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - I was speaking more of POST requests seem to be breaking in general for this user, all of the symptoms reported are incomplete or invalid POSTs

Comment: @Nick thanks, I get it now. But assuming IE10 has tools like IE9 the user can see those requests being blocked/broken right?

Comment: @NickCraver I added more information related to the errors.

Answer (score 6):

I have Win 8 installed as my main machine and I'm not having any issues with our sites on IE 10.0.9200.16384.

Are there any files not being sent to your browser (e.g. http status `404`)?  You can check this from the *F12 developer tools* -> *Network* tab -> *Start capturing* button.

When you try to do any asynchronous operations, e.g. voting, inline editing, what does that *Network* tab show?  Are the requests failing? Are there any errors in the *Console* tab?

On these asynchronous operations, we're seeing you receive `500` server errors on each one, specifically the ones that have our [CSRF prevention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) mechanisms in place.  This leads me to think you're not sending your [`fkey` form value](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74154/what-is-the-fkey-thats-present-on-some-pages-and-what-does-it-do) on your ajax `POST` requests.

Thanks for helping us debug this.

Comment: So how exactly do I send my fkey form value on my ajax POST requests?

Comment: There were no errors, and yes I am receiving 500 server errors, and the response body I receive is at the end of my question.

Comment: See if your `fkey` is being set; just type [`StackExchange.options.user.fkey` into your *Console* tab](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1Bkno.png).

Comment: >> StackExchange.options.user.fkey 
"'StackExchange' is undefined"

Comment: opened a new window, tried again: StackExchange.options.user.fkey: "f7bdd3972cecb8c5d67682d506b67085"

but I still can't upvote.

Comment: Can you try reproducing the behavior in IE's [InPrivate Browsing](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/What-is-InPrivate-Browsing) mode?

Comment: It is reproducible in IE InPrivate mode. Click Vote Up, get an error has occurred box, StackExchange.options.user.fkey has a value set.