# Why doesn't Stack Overflow use an AntiForgeryToken?

Tags: discussion, csrf

I was looking into the HTML forms of Stack Overflow and I realized that it doesn't use AntiForgeryToken. So I created a localhost page with the forms of Stack Overflow, posted something and it worked.

So, why doesn't Stack Overflow use it?

Comment: Why would it need to?

Comment: I doubt it "worked". What exactly did this form do? What action did it perform? Any POST action must send some key to actually do anything.

Comment: I posted to /questions/ask/submit

Comment: And why is that a problem that you could submit that question?

Comment: @Popular Demand because I can create a malicious page that sends data when you access it.

Comment: @MuriloKunze: did that action of your bypass any restrictions? Can you do anything you wouldn't be able to do via the main site?

Comment: @MuriloKunze - are you sure that it would render "correctly" on the site? What you are posting is text for a question/answer. This is read out of the database and converted to HTML for display. I would be very surprised if what you input wasn't sanitised in some way most likely before storage in the database.

Comment: You posted to `/questions/ask/submit` and then what? Has a new question been created? If so, what question exactly?

Comment: OK, [here you go](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74154/what-is-the-fkey-thats-present-on-some-pages-and-what-does-it-do).

Comment: There *is* a field for this; it's named `fkey`

Comment: @Andrew Barber Yeah, I did not see it, Thank you very much.

Comment: @pop, shawizdoward - in theory, a malicious site *could* indeed fill in a hidden form and post questions in he user's name wihout a token.

Comment: @Pekka while I admit I wasn't sure about the technical details, my comment was primarily intended to hint to the OP that suggestions should come with justifications/rationales. Otherwise what's the difference between this and "why isn't SO's color scheme more blue," "why doesn't SO award nine points per upvote instead of ten"....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **Ask Question** page *does* use tokens:

```
<div class="edit-block">
        <input id="fkey" name="fkey" type="hidden" value="********************************">
        <input id="author" name="author" type="text">
    <input type="hidden" name="i1l" value="********************************************">
</div>
```